# AWS -Is it possible to grant access permissions to an S3 object using my client's AWS Account Id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I want to allow a certain AWS account read permissions to one of my S3 objects (file) via a URL. 
Is it possible to grant permissions to other AWS account using his AWS account ID (The user's AWS account Id is the only information I have about his account)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  You want to use the [Principal](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Principal) element.

You can find examples [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

(I know links are generally frowned upon, but AWS technologies change at such a rapid pace that actual examples may be obsolete within days or months)